# How to pinpoint what is causing NotSerializableException in JAVA

Tags: java, serialization

I am working on a game and using serialization to save the game. Sometimes when I save the game I receive a long exception that ends(or starts) with this:

```
 java.io.NotSerializableException: java.awt.image.BufferedImage
```

I know BufferedImage is not serializable and I know how to fix the problem but I cant find which object is containing the BufferedImage.

Is there an easy way to find  which line of code is using that BufferedImage or even name of the class of the object that contains it?

Stacktrace sends me to inside of the  ObjectOutputStream which is useless.

```
Sep 29, 2019 6:51:56 PM main.Main test
SEVERE: null
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.awt.image.BufferedImage
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:162)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1707)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:482)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Container.java:3687)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:162)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1707)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:482)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Container.java:3687)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:162)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1707)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:482)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Container.java:3687)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:162)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1707)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:482)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Container.java:3687)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:762)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:762)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at cTools.Tools.serialize(Tools.java:433)
at main.Main.test(Main.java:38)
at GUI.ActionDialog.jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionDialog.java:378)
at GUI.ActionDialog.access$1100(ActionDialog.java:17)
at GUI.ActionDialog$12.actionPerformed(ActionDialog.java:212)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

basically I click a button and calls the test method and serialization tries to serialize an object that contains BufferedImage.

And this is my serialization code if it is somehow relevant.

```
public static void serialize(Object o, String dirAndFileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(dirAndFileName);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
    out.writeObject(o);
    out.close();
}
```

Here is the test code as requested:

```
System.out.println("Saving test");
    try {

        System.out.println("passeff");
        cTools.Tools.serialize(main.turnHandler.latestEvent.passEffect, getSaveDir() + "t1");
        System.out.println("denyeff");
        cTools.Tools.serialize(main.turnHandler.latestEvent.denyEffect, getSaveDir() + "t15");

        System.out.println("desires");
        cTools.Tools.serialize(main.turnHandler.latestEvent.desireEffects, getSaveDir() + "t2");
        System.out.println("latestevent");
        cTools.Tools.serialize(main.turnHandler.latestEvent, getSaveDir() + "t3");
        System.out.println("normal save");
        save();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Here I am trying to figure out what is causing the error. The program throws the error after console says "passeff"

Comment: Full stacktrace please. Ignore ObjectOutputStream. Is it called by some `writeObject` method?

Comment: I don't use custom serialization. I will add fulll stack trace

Comment: Please post the Main.test method.

Comment: This might be closer than main: `cTools.Tools.serialize(Tools.java:433)`

Comment: currently I am constantly changing it to figure out where the exception is thrown but I can post a state of it that throws the error.

Comment: markspace that is the code I posted. It is how I serialize objects

Comment: @markspace The code for this is in the question. But this code is serializing an ArrayList, containing an other ArrayList, containing some AWT stuff.

Comment: Are you by chance serializing an (anonymous) inner class?

Comment: Well there you go.  Serialize the objects in the ArrayList one at a time until you find which one causes the error.  One of those AWT objects is not serializeable.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Possibly.  Shall I focus my search on anonymous classes?

Comment: Guys check this out : During testing I received this : `java.io.NotSerializableException: GUI.CouncilDialog$4` the object I tried to serialize definitely didn't contain a CouncilDialog object but it was called from the CouncilDialog. I don't understand why this is happening. I also saw a class giving this error even though I made every single variable int it transient. I think serialization is broken or something.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you have some root object like JFrame, JWindows or Frame, Window, which contain further objects. Start from from the root. Traverse all children components, i.e. take all children and check their type. For components check their nested components, etc.

If the top level object is not a Swing/AWT component, the idea is the same: Traverse the object hierarchy from the top to the bottom.

Comment: to my knowledge, I am not serializing any interface component. Have you seen in the stack trace anything that would suggest otherwise?

Comment: If your top level object is not a Swing/AWT component, the approach is the same: Traverse the whole object hierarchy from the top to the bottom until you find need object.